# Is that possible to find an $N_{\epsilon }$ such that for every $x,n\geq N $, $\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}>\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is that possible to find an $N_{\epsilon }$ such that for every $x$ and for every $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$, $\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}>\epsilon$. If yes, what will be the function of $N$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

I'm trying to prove that the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ doesn't converge uniformly to $e^x$. I know how to prove it using sup-difference-test but still trying to prove it directly using definition.

Comment: The infinite series expansion of $e^x$ does converge uniformly to $e^x$. Please check this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594724/uniform-convergence-involving-ex)

Comment: @AnirbanMandal Only on bounded intervals, not on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @monotonic: do you want $\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^k/k! > \epsilon$ or $\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^k/k! < \epsilon$??

Comment: $>\epsilon $ to obtain a contradiction of uniform convergence

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate your series at $x=0$? (Hint: you get $0$ if $n\geq1$).

Comment: At x=0, the series equals 1? But now we want the statement hold for all x.

Comment: Please observe that your statement is not logically equivalent to "does not converge uniformly". For proving the negation it is sufficient to find a specific $\epsilon_0>0$, a specific $N_\epsilon$ and a specific $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\| e^{x_0} - \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{x_{0}^{k}}{k!}\|>\epsilon_0$ for all $n>N_\epsilon$.

Comment: Please observe that your statement is not logically equivalent to "does not converge uniformly" (to $e^x$). For proving the negation it is necessary and sufficient to find a specific $\epsilon_0>0$ and a specific $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $N>0$ there is a $n_0 > N$ such that $\| e^{x_0} - \sum_{k=0}^{n_0} \frac{x_{0}^{k}}{k!}\|>\epsilon_0$ . Please ignore my wrong comment above, I was too slow in editing it.

Answer (score 2):

The series does not converge uniformy on $\mathbb{R}$. If $\sum_{k\ge n}x^k/k!<\epsilon$ for all $x$, then $x^n/n!<\epsilon$ for all $x>0$, which abviously false for $x$ large enough.

However, the answer to your question is no, since for all $x$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\ge n}\frac{x^k}{k!}=0.
$$
What is true is that $\sum_{k\ge n}x^k/k!>\epsilon$ for some (but not all) $x$. Given $n$ let $x_n=(n!)^{1/n}$. Then
$$
\sum_{k\ge n}\frac{x_n^k}{k!}>\frac{x_n^n}{n!}=1.
$$

Comment: I think we should be able to find it since the series doesn't converge to e^x uniformly? Then we can use this to obtain a contradiction?

Comment: I am sorry. I read $<\epsilon$ instead of $>\epsilon$. I will edit acordingly.

Comment: But can we actually find such $x$ in terms of $\epsilon $ though? Just an alternative proof by directly negating the statement.

Comment: Yes, I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even more demonstrative is to take $x=n$ and to observe that for the degree $n$ term one has
$$
\frac{n^n}{n!}\sim e^n
$$
which gets arbitrarily large as $n$ grows. In total contradiction to the behavior you need to apply the Weierstraß theorem on uniform convergence.